# Looping same key JSON nodes

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I'm trying to spit out all the scenes from a user in a JSON chunk, but I'm missing something...

Would you like to take a look?

I put it here as well:
http://jsfiddle.net/RBergante/2HwEH/

Here's what I have:

```
function scenes(){
    var allscenes = new Array();
    for (var i in data.users){
        allscenes = data.users[i].scenes.scene;
        document.write(allscenes[i] + "</br>");
    }
}

var data={"users":[
    {
        "firstName":"Rick",
        "lastName":"Villalobos",
        "pic":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTg2NTEyNTE3NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjY3NzM0OA@@._V1._SY209_CR1,0,140,209_.jpg",
        "scenes": {
            "scene": "In the Woods",
            "scene": "City lights",
            "scene": "Marnon Willis"                        
        },
        "joined": {
            "month":"January",
            "day":12,
            "year":2012
        }
    },
    {
        "firstName":"John",
        "lastName":"Jones",
        "pic":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTU4MDA1NDU1NV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjYzNTYxOA@@._V1._SY209_CR0,0,140,209_.jpg",
        "joined": {
            "month":"April",
            "day":28,
            "year":2010
        }
    }   
]}

scenes();
```

Thanks!

Comment: "John" doesn´t have any scenes; Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scene' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because an object cannot have more than one property of the same key. Scenes should be an array:

```
"scenes": ["In the Woods", "City lights", "Marnon Willis"]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2HwEH/1/

- Also, when looping through an array, do not use `for-in` as it will also run over array properties, not just the indexed content. Use `for` or `while` instead.
- Additionally, you should not use `document.write()`, especially after the page finishes loading (eg. being called in a function later).

Comment: Why the use of join though?

Comment: @RogerBergante I just did a quick join to get the values and join into a single string. If you want to get them individually, you could loop through them.

Comment: funnily enough if I remove the join, the nodes appear in the page also put together with a single comma...